# Unable to connect to Database using MySQLdb in Robotframework

Tags: database, connection, mysql-python, robotframework

Using Robotframework 2.6.3 and the python database library, I want to connect to MySql Database.

I have downloaded the DatabaseLibrary and MySQLdb however when I try to connect using:

```
Library DatabaseLibrary

DatabaseLibrary.Connect To Database MySQLdb cts1    root    password  172.16.7.20
```

I get the following error, when I run this using pybot:

```
OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '172.16.7.20' (10061)")
```

Note:
cts1 - is the DB name and 172.16.7.20 - is the IP address of DB.

This works when I use mysql under the command prompt.  Why would it not be able to connect?

Comment: I am able to connnect with MySQLDb in python just not in robotframework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was I did not provide any PORT into robotframework and it does not correctly use the default port of 3306.  Once I put the port in, it worked.